# Java Jersey 2 implementing filters

Tags: java, jersey, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I want to include a filter so i can check basic auth headers for each request

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;

@Provider
@PreMatching 
public class CheckRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider();


        /*if (sp.authenticateSP(requestContext.getHeaderString("authorization"))     == false){ */
            requestContext.abortWith(
                        Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("User cannot be authenticated")
                        .build());

}}
//}
```

So far that's what i've come up with following the documentation here https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#filters-and-interceptors

My problems is that i don't know how to include a filter so i can test it (i.e copy pasting the first example is not working) and if my approach is correct.

I want to limit it for certain requests in the future but for now i just want to to work.

Comment: You need to add the filter class in Web.xml

Comment: @user1354678 I don't have web.xml. I don't need one. I use jersey 2

Comment: Is is just not working? Try to annotate the class with javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider

Comment: I also think, you might want to use this one: ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: @znurgl Adding Provider & PreMatching made the first example in documentation work. I'm tweaking my code but with no avail so far.

Comment: @znurgl Now i understood what you said about the Container. It worked like a charm. Please post it as answer so i can select it for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ContainerRequestFilter

Here is the API: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html

An here is an example:

```
public class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                    throws IOException {

        final SecurityContext securityContext =
                    requestContext.getSecurityContext();
        if (securityContext == null ||
                    !securityContext.isUserInRole("privileged")) {

                requestContext.abortWith(Response
                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .entity("User cannot access the resource.")
                    .build());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Adding @Provider should also be included if it fails!